# p:commandLink in PrimeFaces needs onclick effect

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using `<p:commandlink>` tag in PrimeFaces. I am unable to get the `onclick` effect of the link.

More Details:

```
<p:commandLink class="one" action="#{class.method}" id="button">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{class.action}" value="ONE"/>
    <h:graphicImage class="one" url="download/one.png" alt="ONE" 
                    style="width: 85%; height: 85%;"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

I have image `one.png` used as button, I need the `onclick` effect onto this button. I tried using `id="button"` with the below code in JS:

```css
#button{}

#button:active {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 2px;
}

.one a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

It is not showing any button click effect.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What do you mean by onclick effect?

Comment: when we use button, we have the onclick effect, we click and it looks like we clicked it.

Comment: I think he means the `:foucs` or `:active` or `:hover` CSS selectors! Maybe!

Comment: yes Hatem, you are at the right place! do you know how I do that?

Comment: I tried using :active and :hover, it is not showing any effect.

Comment: Why not use a p:commandButton for the navigation instead if you need a onclick effect?

Comment: since I need to use the setPropertyActionListener which is not possible in commandbutton, I have to use the commandLink